# Multiple conditions in a like function

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have a set of data, each point either starts with a `AB`, `PO`, or `LV`. there are also a number of entries with things I don't want like `MC` or `BV`. I also have some dates, it looks like this.

```
Select distinct clm.Theletter, clm.thenotedate, clm.theorigdate
from table.table
where clm.thenotedate>= ''2018-01-21'' and clm.theorigdate>''2018-01-01'' 
and clm.Theletter_NUM LIKE ''HP%''
order by clm.thenotedate asc
);
```

and I get a list of everything I want that starts with `AB`, but I also want the stuff that starts with `PO` and `LV`? I tried using OR after my first LIKE but it seems to ignore the date functions and retrieve everything before 2018-01-01 that starts with `PO` and `LV`, which is a lot.

Comment: `and substring(clm.Theletter_NUM, 1, 2) in ('AB', 'PO','LV')`

Comment: `AND (clm.Theletter_NUM LIKE 'AB%' OR clmTheletter_NUM LIKE 'PO%'...)`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Don't forget that you can group logical operations with parentheses to prevent, for instance, the date comparisons from being ignored when you add an OR clause: `(origdate > a AND origdate < b) AND (letters like 'AB%' OR letters like 'PO%')`

Comment: SQLCliff thank you that worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably simplest if you do:

```
. . . and
left(clm.Theletter_NUM, 2) in ('AB', 'PO', 'LV')
```

Most databases support a `left()` function on strings.  If not, just use the appropriate substring function.

Answer (score 0):

You need write again the name of the row after the first like.

```
Select *
From table
Where row like 1 or row like 2
```

Or you can use in

```
Where row in ('1', '2', '3')
```